# Sorting on click API data from url

Tags: javascript, json, api, sorting

I want to sort parameters: id, salary and age at the click of a button.
Suppose I have to dynamically clean my table (deleteRow), sort and then display the data again. However, seems to be difficult. Can somebody help me? Is there a better way?

JavaScript:

```js
const butt = document.getElementById('button');
const swTable = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
const url = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees';

function fetchFromUrl(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json()
  });
}

function createElement(nameOfTag, text) {
  const element = document.createElement(nameOfTag);
  const content = document.createTextNode(text);
  element.appendChild(content);
  return element;
}

function createTable(data) {
  const table = document.createElement('tr');
  const {
    id,
    employee_name,
    employee_salary,
    employee_age
  } = data;

  table.appendChild(createElement('td', id))
  table.appendChild(createElement('td', employee_name))
  table.appendChild(createElement('td', employee_salary))
  table.appendChild(createElement('td', employee_age))
  return table;
}

fetchFromUrl('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(result => {
      const row = createTable(result);
      swTable.appendChild(row);
    })
  });
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS</title>

  <body>
    <table id=table>
      <thead>
        <th><button id=id> id </button> </th>
        <th><button id=name> employee name </button> </th>
        <th><button id=salary> employee salary </button> </th>
        <th><button id=age>  employee age </button> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>

    </table>

    <script type="module" src='main.js' type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What error do you come up with? Help us help you. Is there a better way is too broad of a question.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Comment: Please do not delete a question if someone has spent time composing an answer and posting it. If the answer is helpful to you, it will probably be helpful to future users and visitors. You can accept @zagkaretos's answer by clicking on the checkmark, but by no means are you obligated to.

Answer (score 6):

Using plain JavaScript, you can use a function for sorting the `data` array and then replace old `tbody` with the new one.

For example:

```
function sortByField(field) {
  if (field == 'id') {
    data.sort((a,b) => (Number(a.id) > Number(b.id)) ? 1 : ((Number(b.id) > Number(a.id)) ? -1 : 0)); 
  } else if (field == 'name') {
    data.sort((a,b) => (a.employee_name > b.employee_name) ? 1 : ((b.employee_name > a.employee_name) ? -1 : 0)); 
  } else if (field == 'salary') {
    data.sort((a,b) => (Number(a.employee_salary) > Number(b.employee_salary)) ? 1 : ((Number(b.employee_salary) > Number(a.employee_salary)) ? -1 : 0)); 
  } else if (field == 'age') {
    data.sort((a,b) => (Number(a.employee_age) > Number(b.employee_age)) ? 1 : ((Number(b.employee_age) > Number(a.employee_age)) ? -1 : 0)); 
  }

  var old_tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
  var new_tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  new_tbody.setAttribute('id', 'tbody');
  data.forEach(result => {
    const row = createTable(result);
    new_tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
  old_tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(new_tbody, old_tbody);
}
```

And add `onclick` event handlers on buttons:

```
onclick="sortByField('id')"
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ubr5mKuO9YIfMfT8hbXG?p=preview) you can find a working example.

Note that I used `Number` to convert strings to numbers while sorting.

Of course, you can use [Underscore library](https://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) to perform the sorting, JQuery library to select html elements etc.

And take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value) on different ways you can sort an array of objects.

Comment: @Izagkaretos 

Great solution, thank you very much. However, I'm wondering if the data can be loaded straight from the api, instead of copying (var data = [{"id": "7150", "employee_name": "vanja1", "employee_salary": "45454" etc.) ?

Comment: Sure, you can load the data array as you wish. I used a fixed array, because I couldn't load from `http://dummy.restapiexample.com` endpoint from `https://plnkr.co`.